# Complexity of subset product

Tags: math, complexity-theory

I have a set of numbers produced using the following formula with integers 0 < x < a.

```
f(x) = f(x-1)^2 % a
```

For example starting at 2 with a = 649.

```
{2, 4, 16, 256, 636, 169, 5, 25, 649, 576, 137, ...}
```

I am after a subset of these numbers that when multiplied together equals 1 mod N.

I believe this problem by itself to be NP-complete (based on similaries to Subset-Sum problem).

However starting with any integer (x) gives the same solution pattern.

Eg. a = 649

{2,  4,  **16**, 256, 636, 169,   **5**,  25, 649, **576**, 137, ...} = 16 * 5 * 576 = 1 % 649
{3,  9,  **81**,  71, 498,  86, **257**, 500, 135,  **53**, 213, ...} = 81 * 257 * 53 = 1 % 649
{4, 16, **256**, 636, 169,   5,  **25**, 649, 576, **137**, 597, ...} = 256 * 25 * 137 = 1 % 649

I am wondering if this additional fact makes this problem solvable faster?
Or if anyone has run into this problem previously or has any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `f(x) = g^(2^x) % a`, where `g=f(0)`.  You can use Euler's theorem to find some `f(x)` to multiply together to get 1.  [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) states that `g^Phi(a) % a = 1` (`Phi(a)` = [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) = # of integers `< a` which are relatively prime to `a`).  So you just need to compute `Phi(a)`, then decompose it into its bit representation and pick the appropriate `x` to set the bits that add together to make `Phi(a)`.

Perhaps an example would be clearer.  Let `a = 54`, then `Phi(a) = 18`.  Then `18 = 2^4 + 2^1`, so `f(4) * f(1) = g^(2^4+2^1) = g^18 = 1` mod `a`.

All that is straightforward, but you do need to compute `Phi(a)`.  This is hard in general (equivalent to factoring `a`), but it can be easy if, for example, you know that `a` is prime.

Note that this solution does not depend on the value of `g = f(0)`, other than the fact that `g` and `a` are relatively prime (if they aren't, then there aren't any solutions).

In your case, `Phi(649) = 580 = 2^9 + 2^6 + 2^2`, so you multiply together f(2), f(6), and f(9).

Answer (score 2):

The subset product problem is proven NP complete as well, and has an even stronger resemblance to this:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/famous_math_problems/subset_product_problem/oa/xp/7d/

Subset sum is actually solvable in pseudo polynomial time, O(nC) where C = The total "weight" (eg 649). I don't know if a similar thing is possible with subset product.